# POCO entity generator or edmgen entityclassgeneration: Performance issues

Tags: performance, entity-framework, poco, edmgen

I am working on a project where performance is a key factor for success. I need to decide whether to use POCO entity generator or not. I might use entityclassgeneration instead of the POCO but I'm not sure if performance may be affected.

Another thing I should consider is the fact of having to work with stored procedures. I'm not sure if using the POCO entity generator template will give me some problems later in the development phase. Specially with the stored procedures.

Any advice would be helpful about using POCO entity generator or entityclassgeneration. By the way, I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 and MySQL database.

Comment: If performance is critical: stored procedures. Best support for stored procedures in EF 5: database first => edmx. But you can use Visual Studio can't you?

Comment: Yeah, I'm using Visual Studio with EF 5. Because of the big model, had to split the db model in different edmx and then manipulate the csdl to avoid duplicate entities and relationships.